# android listview alternate background color

Tags: android, listview

I have worked through the different answers on how to alternate the background color of a list view, but neither way works properly.

I extended the `SimpleCursorAdapter` and set the *background color* depending on the line number:

```
private class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private ViewHolder holder;
    private int layoutRessource;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context applicationContext, int layout, Cursor cursor,
                                 String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(applicationContext, layout, cursor, from, to, 0);
        layoutRessource = layout;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.getTextAbove().setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        holder.getTextBelow().setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ICDTxt")));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered newView");
        View view = mInflater.inflate(layoutRessource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.setTextAbove((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_code));
        holder.setTextBelow((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_description));
        holder.setLayout((LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rowLayout));
        view.setTag(holder);
        return view;
    }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         Log.d(TAG, "entered get View");
         Log.d(TAG, "convertView == null: " + (convertView == null));
        View rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if ( position % 2 == 0 ) {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            // rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listBackgroundEven);
        } else {
            rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listBackgroudOdd);
        }
        return rowView;
    }





       private class ViewHolder {
                private TextView textAbove = null, textBelow = null;            

                public TextView getTextAbove() {
                    return textAbove;
                }

                public void setTextAbove(TextView textAbove) {
                    this.textAbove = textAbove;
                }

                public TextView getTextBelow() {
                    return textBelow;
                }

                public void setTextBelow(TextView textBelow) {
                    this.textBelow = textBelow;
                }
            }
```

The custom LayoutXML for the lines of the listview

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_code"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large"
        android:textColor="@color/fontColor"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_description"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/fontColor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This works but only changes the backgroundcolor of the text in each line. I would like to change the background color of the whole line. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Change background color of `listView` on your `xml`. Looks like you are chaning color of `ListView item`

Comment: Of course the item should be taken. Set the Color of convertView directly. Remove that rowView completely.

Comment: If I try to setBackground directly on convertView, I retrieve a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all you are missing is to inflate() but I am not sure you want to set the color of the ListView when you have 2 child TextViews. There are 2 options that I know of. You can set the background of the current view (**convertView**, in this case ListView) or set it on the child UI element in ListView instead of the parent view, **convertView**. If you set on the ListView, try this (I did not do this). Sample code in getView():

```
if (convertView == null) {
       // Inflate somehow
       convertView = LayoutInflater.from(thisContext).inflate(<custom LayoutXML>, ...
    ...
    }
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

If instead you set it on your TextView, and this is what I do. Sample code:

```
if (convertView == null) {
   // Inflate somehow
   convertView = LayoutInflater.from(thisContext).inflate(<custom LayoutXML>, ...
...
}
TextView tvDescr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_description);
tvDescr.setBackgroundResource(R.color.BLUE);
```